# RaspController equivalent for Windows or webapp?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am using the RaspController app on Android to manage my Raspberries and like it very much. For those who don't know it, it allows you to control almost everything remotely on Raspberries.

I was wondering if there was an equivalent application on Windows? Or maybe something that would run on the Raspberry and be accessible from a web browser? The idea would be to be able to control several Raspberries from the same interface.